# Logs not written in Elasticsearch using NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch

Tags: c#, asp.net, elasticsearch, logging, nlog

I'm trying to get working the NLog with target to Elasticsearch in my asp.net web API application.

The .net framework version of my application is 4.6.

I'm using Elasticsearch, Nest and Elasticsearch.NET V. 5.6.

NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch V 3.0.0

NLog 4.4.3

Following is my NLog.config

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name="nlog" type="NLog.Config.ConfigSectionHandler, NLog"/>
  </configSections>
<nlog xmlns="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd"
        xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.nlog-project.org/schemas/NLog.xsd NLog.xsd"
        autoReload="true"
        throwExceptions="true"
        throwConfigExceptions="true"
        internalLogLevel="Off"
        internalLogFile="c:\temp\nlog-internal.log">
  <extensions>
    <add assembly="NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch"/>
  </extensions>
  <targets>
    <target 
          name="logfile" 
          xsi:type="File" 
          fileName="Nlog.txt" />

    <target name="elastic"
              xsi:type="BufferingWrapper"
              bufferSize="1"
              flushTimeout="1">
      <target xsi:type="ElasticSearch"
              layout="${logger} | ${threadid} | ${message}"
              index="test-log-${date:format=yyyy.MM.dd}"
              includeAllProperties="true"
              uri="http://###.###.###.###:9200/">

        <field name="user"
               layout="${windows-identity:userName=True:domain=False}"/>
        <field name="host"
               layout="${machinename}"/>
      </target>
    </target>    
  </targets>

  <rules>
    <logger enabled="true" name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="logfile" />
    <logger enabled="true" name="*" minlevel="Debug" writeTo="elastic" />
  </rules>
</nlog>
</configuration>
```

In the API I have a method for testing the log entry.

```
private static NLog.Logger _logger = NLog.LogManager.GetCurrentClassLogger();

        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpGet]
        public HttpResponseMessage Hello()
        {
            _logger.Info("Hello World!!!!!!!!!!!!");
            _logger.Trace("Sample trace message");
            _logger.Debug("Sample debug message");
            _logger.Info("Sample informational message");
            _logger.Warn("Sample warning message");
            _logger.Error("Sample error message");
            _logger.Fatal("Sample fatal error message");
            return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, "Hello World!");
        }
```

I can see the Log entry in the Nlog.txt file but nothing in Elasticsearch.
I downloaded the **NLog.Targets.ElasticSearch** project and attached to my application in order to debug it.
Debugging it, I can see in the following code

```
private void SendBatch(ICollection<AsyncLogEventInfo> events)
        {
            try
            {
                var logEvents = events.Select(e => e.LogEvent);

                var payload = FormPayload(logEvents);

                var result = _client.Bulk<byte[]>(payload);

                if (!result.Success)
```

that result.Seccess is equal true.
So no exceptions, but I don't se the log index to be created.
The web API already works properly with Elasticsearch.

Can someone help me to understand what is wrong? Did I miss something?
Thanks in advance for your time.

Comment: Are you configuring it correctly in your startup.cs in Configure method?   something like this :   
app.AddNLogWeb();
env.ConfigureNLog(env.IsProduction() ? "wwwroot/nlogELK.config" : "wwwroot/nlogELKPreprod.config");

Comment: I don't think this is my case since I'm not using ASP.NET Core. Anyway as I wrote, the api application is picking up the right config since I can see logs entry in the txt file.

Comment: Maybe it can help: https://github.com/NLog/NLog/issues/2435#issuecomment-358292765